# How can a javascript variable that I just displayed immediately error out as undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple javascript code that looks like this:

```
var divLink = $(this).attr("href");
alert(divLink);
if ($(divlink).is(":visible")) $(divLink).hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
```

It throws this error on line 3:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: divlink is not defined
```

I put in line two just to see what was in the variable divLink. It returns:

```
The page at mysite.com says:

#categories_settings
```

Once I click "OK" on the dialog box, it throws the error. How can this be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS is case-sensitive. Use `divLink` consistently, and not `divlink`.

That resolves the reference error. @epascarello's answer solves other issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
var divLink = $(this).attr("href");  <--string
alert(divLink);
if ($(divlink).is(":visible"))  <--acting like it is a jQuery object and it has a lowercase l.
```

The code should be

```
var divLink = $(this);
alert(divLink.attr("href"));
if (divLink.is(":visible")) {
    divLink.hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
}
```